# Parsing yaml file in Gradle project without downloading from the repository

Tags: java, gradle, yaml, build.gradle, nexus

I have a Java `gradle` project. I need to parse a `yaml` file (which creates Java classes) that is in a nexus repository. I have an option of downloading `yaml` from the repository. Futhermore, I could do a parsing in my project. However, I do not want the `yaml` files in my project. Is there a way to parse `yaml` file directly from the repository (I mean on the fly) and create java classes in the project?

Finally, can anyone suggest any proper design, if there is something wrong with my solution?

Comment: You should have the url of that repository

Comment: If suppose I have the URL. Can I parse yaml file directly over the network without downloading the file?
Can you please share an example code snippet for this.

Comment: If you have the url, you can access to that file, and analyze that yaml

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `url` on you repository

Comment: Only adding url of yaml file would work and parsing happen directly you mean??
If yes can you please show me a template for parsing yaml file present in a repository directly without downloading.